# Optimizing a standard deviation function Pandas Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, function, numpy

The `std` pandas function below calculates the standard deviation of every nth value defined by `number`. So it would take the the values of `PC_list` with indexes `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` and calculate the standard deviation and then the indexes `[1,2,3,4,5]` and calculate the standard deviation until the end of `PC_list`. I am trying to optimize the code by trying to make it run faster even though it is very fast as of now I want to see as to how much more I could increase the performance by. Is there a way I could maybe increase the performance by using `np.split` to divide it into chunks or some other method that would decrease the runtime. The original `PC_list` has over 2.6 million arrays and it takes the `std` function about `150 ms` to run, The current `PC_list` array is a portion of it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

PC_list = np .array([417.88 417.88 418.24 417.88 418.6  418.6  418.6  418.6  418.6  418.75 418.75 418.75 418.75 418.56 418.56 419.19 418.95 419.19 419.38 419.38 419.43 418.75 418.57 419.31 419.51 416.08 416.   416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74 416.74])
number = 5
std= pd.Series(PC_list).rolling(number).std().dropna().to_numpy()
```

Comment: standard deviation has to inspect all the entries of the array ... you could *sample the array* to get an *approximation* of the standard deviation ... that would be faster, but less accurate of course

Comment: There are special algorithms for rolling stds. Bottleneck provides such implementations. (move_std) https://github.com/pydata/bottleneck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `numpy` is a `pandas` dependency, which is why `pandas` vectorized functions are so fast, but for little more speed, use `@numba.njit` as a function decorator.
- Use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to call the `.std()`

  - [Numba Performance Tips](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html)
  - *Numba translates Python functions to optimized machine code at runtime*
  - [`.njit`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html?highlight=njit#what-is-nopython-mode)
- [pandas User Guide: Enhancing Performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#enhancing-performance)

  - As shown in the guide, numba requires numpy arrays from pandas.
- Over the entire sample size range, using `.std()` with `@numba.njit` is `2.2x` faster than `.std()` alone.

```py
import numba
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

@numba.njit
def test(d):
    return d.std()


data = defaultdict(list)

for x in range(100, 596061):  # number of unique elements
    
    # create array
    random.seed(365)
    a = np.random.rand(x, 1) * 1000
    
    # timeit for std with numba
    res1 = %timeit -r2 -n1 -q -o test(a)
    
    # timeit for std without numba
    res2 = %timeit -r2 -n1 -q -o a.std()

    data['std_numba'].append(res1.average)
    data['std'].append(res2.average)
    data['idx'].append(x)

# create a dataframe from data
df = pd.DataFrame(data).iloc[1:, :]

# set the index
df.set_index('idx', inplace=True)

# calculate the rolling mean to smooth out the plot
df = df.rolling(1000).mean()

# calculate the difference
df['diff'] = df['std'] - df['std_numba']

# plot
ax = df.plot( xlabel='number of rows', ylabel='time (s)', figsize=(8, 6))
ax.grid()
```

[image]